# Is it possible to flushright the right-hand side with systeme without \hphantom?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, systeme

I typeset some systems of equations, and I really like the format of input (as well as the output) the systeme package provides.

Now, I wonder if there is a way to flushright also the right-hand side of the equation, without using `\hphantom`? In the example below, I get the result as I want in the second system, but not the first. But I do it with a `\hphantom`.

```
 \documentclass{minimal}
 \usepackage{systeme}
 \begin{document}
 \[
 \systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
 \]
 \[
 \systeme{x+y=\hphantom{-}2,x-y=-2}
 \]
 \end{document}
```

giving

[image: The output of the example]

**Update**

Just in case someone wonders why on earth one would like to have the right-hand side flushright, here is an image that might explain it better. Without the right-hand side being flushright, the arrows look bad not ending at the same horizontal location.

[image: showcase]

Also, I can mention that I have read the documentation of the systeme package, and I did not find anything like this (but my french is rusty). I also browsed the source of the package, but that was too complicated for me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The package `systeme` offers different alignment options for the left and the right hand sides. Default is `r,l`, that is, unknowns right aligned and constant terms left aligned. This can be changed using `\sysalign`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\sysalign{r,r}% default is r,l
\systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Issue the `\sysalign` declaration in the preamble if you want it to hold for every system.

---

## original answer (with older update)

It's a choice of the package to have the last column aligned left and, as far as I can see, there's no provision for changing it by setting an option.

You can change it by redefining the command `\SYS@makesyspreamble@i` that's responsible for setting the alignment in columns; the simplest way is to use `regexpatch`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SYS@makesyspreamble@i}
  {$##$\hfil\null}% left alignment
  {\hfil$##$\null}% right alignment
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Should you need to switch between left and right alignment, here's how to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SYS@makesyspreamble@i}
 {$##$\hfil\null}
 {\span\SYSX@afterequalalignment\null}
 {}{}
\newcommand{\SYSX@afterequalalignmentleft}{$##$\hfil}% default
\newcommand{\SYSX@afterequalalignmentright}{\hfil$##$}% default
\newcommand{\rightalignafterequal}{%
  \let\SYSX@afterequalalignment\SYSX@afterequalalignmentright
}
\newcommand{\leftalignafterequal}{%
  \let\SYSX@afterequalalignment\SYSX@afterequalalignmentleft
}
\leftalignafterequal % default
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
\]
\[
\rightalignafterequal
\systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\rightalignafterequal` declaration obeys the usual scoping rules, so you can issue it in the preamble if you want all systems to have right alignment.

[image]

### UPDATE

The most recent version of `systeme` no longer uses `@` for private macros, so the patch should be modified.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\chardef\savedunderscorecatcode=\catcode`\_
\catcode`\_=11
\xpatchcmd{\SYS_makesyspreamble_i}
 {$##$\hfil\null}
 {\span\SYSX_afterequalalignment\null}
 {}{}
\newcommand{\SYSX_afterequalalignmentleft}{$##$\hfil}% default
\newcommand{\SYSX_afterequalalignmentright}{\hfil$##$}% default
\newcommand{\rightalignafterequal}{%
  \let\SYSX_afterequalalignment\SYSX_afterequalalignmentright
}
\newcommand{\leftalignafterequal}{%
  \let\SYSX_afterequalalignment\SYSX_afterequalalignmentleft
}
\leftalignafterequal % default
\catcode`\_=\savedunderscorecatcode

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
\]
\[
\rightalignafterequal
\systeme{x+y=2,x-y=-2}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful! This does exactly what I want (I will wait a while before accepting the answer, since I've been told to do so).

Comment: Thanks for that update as well! I don't think I will need it, but maybe someone else who stumbles upon this question will. I will mark your answer as accepted, since it really solved my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: This does not seem to work in TeX Live 2023.

Comment: @mf67 The package now offers the choice. I’ll update.

Answer (score 2):

I am reviving this old post because systeme has changed so egreg's solution no longer has any effect, because the patched command name has changed.

To right-align the last column for systeme version 0.32, dated 2019/01/13 use:

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`\_11
\xpatchcmd{\SYS_makesyspreamble_i}
{$##$\hfil\null}% left alignment
{\hfil$##$\null}% right alignment
{}{}
\catcode`\_8
\makeatother
```

I hope egreg would be kind enough to update his solution for switching between right and left alignment (and correct my code if necessary).

Comment: I've checked egreg's alignment switching code and all it needs is the line `\xpatchcmd{\SYS@makesyspreamble@i}` replaced by `\catcode`\_11
\xpatchcmd{\SYS_makesyspreamble_i}`. Not sure if it also should have `\catcode`\_8` at the end.