# Aligning systems of equations by symbol and variable

Tags: equations, align

Using this code:

```
\begin{flalign}
& +3x+2y-5z=+04 \\
& +2x+4y-1z=+12 \\
& -4x-8y+9z=-06 &
\end{flalign}
```

I produce this output:

[image: pre-output]

However, I'd like to produce a similar alignment, but without leading 0's, 1's, and +'s.

I would like my code to produce this:

[image: post-output]

How do I modify my code to produce this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Variant with `\hphantom`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
& \mathbin{\hphantom{+}}3x+2y-5z=\hphantom{+0}4 \\
& \mathbin{\hphantom{+}}2x+4y-\hphantom{1}z=\hphantom{+}12 \\
& -4x-8y+9z=\hphantom{0}{-}6 &
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result \hphantom]

- The space after the `=` is a little too large, because the needed space is the maximum of two digits or one digit with sign instead of one sign with two digits. Since the sign is larger than a digit, the `1` of `12` is set via `\llap`.
- Also, I do not think, the first sign in the line `-4x` should be spaced as binary operator, thus the following example uses an unary minus sign instead:

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
& \hphantom{+}3x+2y-5z = \hphantom{+}4 \\
& \hphantom{+}2x+4y-\hphantom{1}z = \hphantom{+}\llap{$1$}2 \\
& {-}4x-8y+9z = {-}6 &
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result optimized \hphantom]

Answer (score 4):

As @vonbrand said, you can easily write systems of equations using `systeme` package, sadly for me the [documentation](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/generic/systeme/systeme_doc_fr.pdf) is in french.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\systeme{3x+2y-5z=4,2x+4y-z=12,-4x-8y+9z=-6}%Default settings

\medskip

\sysdelim{.}{.}\systeme{3x+2y-5z=4,2x+4y-z=12,-4x-8y+9z=-6}%Without the left brace

\medskip

\sysdelim{.}{.}\systeme{3x+2y-5z=4@E_{*},2x+4y-z=12,-4x-8y+9z=-6}%Equations with numbers

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

**UPDATE**

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247070/is-it-possible-to-flushright-the-right-hand-side-with-systeme-without-hphantom) shows you how to the change the alignment of the RHS of the equations in order to do that you just need to redefine the command `\SYS@makesyspreamble@i` as @egreg mentioned

**UPDATE Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SYS@makesyspreamble@i}
{$##$\hfil\null}% left alignment
{\hfil$##$\null}% right alignment
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\systeme{3x+2y-5z=4,2x+4y-z=12,-4x-8y+9z=-6}

\medskip

\sysdelim{.}{.}\systeme{3x+2y-5z=4,2x+4y-z=12,-4x-8y+9z=-6}

\medskip

\sysdelim{.}{.}\systeme{3x+2y-5z=4@E_{*},2x+4y-z=12,-4x-8y+9z=-6}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The alignment of the RHS does not match what the OP requests.

Answer (score 0):

The `systeme` package (in TeXlive and MikTeX) is geared towards this. Haven't used it, though.