# aligning equations in latex problem

Tags: math-mode, align, amsmath

I am using the amsmath package in latex to align three equations.

```
\begin{align*} 
&x_{1} - 3x_{2} + 4x_{3} = -4 \\
3&x_{1} - 7x_{2} + 7x_{3} = -8 \\
-4&x_{1} + 6x_{2} - x_{3} = 7  \\
\end{align*}
```

[image]

how do i get the output shown above to align each of the numbers in columns. I need all of the operands in the same spot and in my output the equal sign is way off.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `systeme` package does this in a very pretty way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{
   x_{1} - 3x_{2} + 4x_{3} = -4,
  3x_{1} - 7x_{2} + 7x_{3} = -8,
 -4x_{1} + 6x_{2} -  x_{3} = 7
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you search on the site for `systeme`, you'll find several other examples.

For instance, in order to have the constant terms flush right, you can look at [Is it possible to flushright the right-hand side with systeme without \hphantom?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247070/is-it-possible-to-flushright-the-right-hand-side-with-systeme-without-hphantom)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SYS@makesyspreamble@i}
  {$##$\hfil\null}% left alignment
  {\hfil$##$\null}% right alignment
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{
   x_{1} - 3x_{2} + 4x_{3} = -4,
  3x_{1} - 7x_{2} + 7x_{3} = -8,
 -4x_{1} + 6x_{2} -  x_{3} = 7
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help but the 7 needs to be lined up with the other items in the column that have a negative sign. how could i do this?

Comment: @user3095790: Use `\phantom{-}7`.

Comment: @user3095790 As I said, looking for `systeme` in the site gives an answer.

Comment: is there any way to display it without the brackets in front of the equations?

Comment: @user3095790 If you never want the brace, add `\sysdelim{.}{.}` in the preamble; or you can do it locally by placing the same command between `\[` (or `\begin{equation}`) and `\systeme`; in this case it will hold only for the next system.