# Make Negative Sign Take Up No Space

Tags: boxes

I have already read the posts detailing how to create text that does not take up any space. My question is if I am doing it correctly in this instance.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\n}{\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}}

\begin{document}
Not using my custom command
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  a_1 & {}-{} & a_2 & {}={} & -3\\
      && a_2 & {}={} & 8\\
      && - a_2 & {}={} & 8
\end{alignat*}

Using my custom command
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  a_1 & {}-{} & a_2 & {}={} & -3\\
      && a_2 & {}={} & 8\\
      && \n a_2 & {}={} & 8
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

The command `\n` seems a bit hacky to me, so I was wondering if there is a better resolution to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition is not really hacky. You can define it a bit simpler using `\llap`:

```
\newcommand\n{\llap{$-$}}
```

`\llap` and `\rlap` are essentially the same as `\makebox[0pt][r]` and `\makebox[0pt][l]`, respectively.

Comment: I usually discourage using `\llap` and `\rlap`. They can have unexpected effects, which `\makebox` hasn't.

Comment: And `\mathllap` (since `mathtools` is loaded, which would simplify the definition of the command)?

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways: the package `systeme` and `autoaligne`. The former has a simpler syntax, the latter is more powerful, but also a bit more difficult when there are missing terms.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{autoaligne}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247070/
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\SYS@makesyspreamble@i}
  {$##$\hfil\null}% left alignment
  {\hfil$##$\null}% right alignment
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
\sysdelim..
\systeme{
  a_1 - a_2 = -3,
  a_2 = 8,
 -a_2= -8
}
\]

\[
\autoaligne[dd]{%
a_1-a_2=-3 \\%
+a_2=8 \\
-a_2=-8
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A correct usage of `alignat` makes things much simpler. Remember that n alignment groups require 2n – 1 ampersands. Actually, here, 2 groups are enough:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
  a_1- a_2 &={} & -3 & \\
       a_2 &= & 8 & \\
       - a_2 & = & 8 & %
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]